# Performance implications of unbinding all jQuery events on all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory, jquery-selectors

I have a single-page "shell" application that can load several modules and all modules have several views. I don't necessarily know or have control over which modules or views are loaded and they can be customized (actions added/removed, dom elements added, etc).

Since it's an SPA, I want to unbind all events when closing each view to avoid high memory usage or leaks. But I don't know what type of events are bound to which element, so on `CloseView()`, I'm doing this this:

```
$(this.accessor + ' *').unbind();
```

Which is essentially `$('#myView *').unbind()` -- unbind all events from all page elements

Sometimes the selector results in ~ 20 DOM elements, but I've seen a high of **320** elements. The average seems to be around 30ish.

Edit for clarity:

Should I be concerned that selecting 300+ elements and unbinding all events can cause performance issues?

Comment: Are you asking if selecting 320 elements and unbinding the events on them can be a performance issue? Your question is not quite clear or specific enough.

Comment: If the events are bound to the view that is to be removed, upon removing said view with a jquery method, all events and data associated to said elements will also be removed. Just make sure your event delegation is also based on the root element of that view.

Comment: Edited my post for clarity, but yes @Blunderfest, that's what I meant.

Comment: @KevinB, yes, I'm removing the view using jquery $(el).remove(); I didn't realize that also unbinds all events, so I guess I shouldn't be so concerned. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit from event delegation via `$("foo").on(...)`.

Comment: @GregBurghardt That's what I'm doing... $('#myView').on('click', '#el', function() {...});

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that jQuery's `$('#el').remove();` **removes all events** bound within that `#el`'s tree, so this is essentially a non-issue. (thanks to @KevinB for the answer)